# bootstrap not able to get correct design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating basic layout from bootstrap,

the image I draw something like this :

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2a7sawn.jpg

I wrote the html like this :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2  col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <div class="sidemargin">
                        <%--<div>
                            <span class="verticaltextname1">Project</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="verticaltextname1">Work History</span>
                        </div>--%>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8  col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                    <div class="mainContent">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-2">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="topBox">About me</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="topBox">Specialization</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-2">
                                        <div class="topBox">Awards</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-2">
                                        <div class="topBox">Testimonials</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="topBox">Project</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="topBox">Description</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="topBox">
                                            WorkedAs
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="topBox">
                                            Responsibilities
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="topBox">Achievement</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="topBox">Client</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="topBox">
                                            Skills
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="topBox">
                                            WorkInvolved
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="topBox">
                                Jquery Carousal
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2  col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <div class="sidemargin">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My problem is, I am not able to get the correct design as per my paper drawing, and I also do not know if the html I wrote is correct or not

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: bootstrap version : 3

Comment: A quick tip - you don't need to specify column widths at each size if they're all the same.  So for example if you have col-xs-2, there's no need to specify col-sm-2, col-lg-2 etc...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for tip, but i am still looking for someone to guid me or hint me to correct my html

Comment: Also I'm not sure you understand how columns work.  Basically you have 12 columns in a row.  A col-xs-2 will take up 2 of those - or 1/6th.  If you want a column that is half the width it would be col-xs-6.  Apologies if you know all of that, just your code suggests you haven't quite grasped it.  For example your top row should have four col-xs-3, if you want it to look like your design

Comment: basically, what i did is , the most parent row have 3 column for outer desgin , so 1st column will be 2+8+2 = 12, is it wrong?

Comment: Yes but your diagram suggests that "About Me" and "Specialisation" should be in col-xs-3, but you have them in col-xs-6.  Also your code has split the top 4 across two rows where they should be in just one row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58706/discussion-between-vir-and-pugfugly).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2BgwG.png, on first yellow row, i put 4 div

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a partial fiddle which will hopefully help you on your way:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7349/)

```
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="topBox">About me</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="topBox">Specialization</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="topBox">Awards</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class=" col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="topBox">Testimonials</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="topBox">Project</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="topBox">Description</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="topBox">Achievements</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class="topBox">Clients</div>
                                </div>                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="topBox">
                                        WorkedAs
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="topBox">
                                        Skills
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="topBox">
                                        Responsibilities
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="topBox">
                                        Work involved
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```